# Cannot set property of undefined CSS DOM

Tags: javascript, css, dom

My JS:         `document.getElementsByClassName('main').style.backgroundColor = '#101521';`

My HTML:

```
<html class= 'main'>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Widg-It</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span id="close">X</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Im trying to make the background of my webpage the color '#101521' using CSS DOM

I run the code and I get the error: "cannot set property of 'backgroundColor' of undefined"

I do not know what this means, and how to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName('main')` returns a list. You want the first one in the list which is in index 0 therefore need to specify that by using [0] which is the first element in the list [1] is second etc

```
document.getElementsByClassName('main')[0].style.backgroundColor = '#101521';
```

also since there will probably be only one html tag or main. i would suggest using `getElementsByTagName()` or `getElementById()`.

**getElementsByTagName()**

**HTML:**
`<html> ... </html>`

**JS**: `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.backgroundColor = '#101521';`

**OR**

**getElementById()**

**HTML:**
`<html id="main"> ... </html>`

**JS**: `document.getElementdById('main').style.backgroundColor = '#101521';`

Its up to you which way you want. All 3 methods will work fine. Hope this helps.